# how to install HEX offline

Tags: hex, elixir, offline

Please is there a workaround for installing HEX offline?

```
D:\Paperless\PeopleCost\server>mix local.hex --force
** (Mix) httpc request failed with: {:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :etimedout}]}

Could not install Hex because Mix could not download metadata at https://repo.hex.pm/installs/hex-1.x.csv.

Alternatively, you can compile and install Hex directly with this command:

    mix archive.install github hexpm/hex branch latest


D:\Paperless\PeopleCost\server>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is: is the hexpm website down or is your internet connection firewalled/down? Do you want to fetch packages from a CD-ROM? (No idea if that's possible but that is how we got our stuff 'offline' in the past...)

Comment: always use a live connection. hexpm  is working. i can access hex.pm from the browser on that server

Comment: Can you access this url from the browser?
https://repo.hex.pm/installs/hex-1.x.csv

Comment: yes, i can @z5ottu

Comment: Do you use a proxy settings in your browser? If you use a proxy, you need to set HTTP_PROXY / HTTPS_PROXY environment variables for command line use. You can list all environment variables with SET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you show hints at the solution.
I checked out the repository for `hex`[1] and you can build your own archive (`.ez` file).

Copy that file into your environment without an online connection and install locally.

I tested this on a Docker instance of `elixir:latest` with Elixir version 1.12.2, hex version 0.21.2, and OTP 24.0.5.

Steps to reproduce:

```
# On a machine with an internet connection
cd /tmp/
git clone https://github.com/hexpm/hex/archive/refs/tags/v0.21.2.tar.gz --output hex.tar.gz 
tar -xzf hex.tar.gz 
cd hex-0.21.2/
./release.sh 0.21.2
```

This should create a bunch of files, but I guess we're only interested in the latest one (i.e., `hex-0.21.2-elixir-1.11.0.ez`).
The filename means that this is an archive for Hex version 0.21.2, and it was built with Elixir version 1.11.0. I test this with a newer Elixir version without issues.
Once you have that archive on your offline machine install it with the following command.

```
mix archive.install /tmp/hex-0.21.2.ez
mix hex.info
```

The last command should show something like below.

```
Hex:    0.21.2
Elixir: 1.12.2
OTP:    24.0.5

Built with: Elixir 1.9.4 and OTP 20.3
```

I think that's about how you should do it.

[1] https://github.com/hexpm/hex